# So, I don't understand how 'self' is never defined

Tags: reactjs, onclick

**How to implement auto onClick button event in reactjs after some interval?**

Comment: You can use ref and setInterval combination to click on button after sometime (If you want button to be clicked). you can also use inline setInterval function in button.

Answer (score 0):

It should be clicked every 5 second. If you need it once use setTimeout instead

```
return (
  <button onClick={setInterval(() => {return null}, 5000)}>Autoclickable</button>
)
```

OR

```
const handleClick = () => {
  console.log('Auto click')
}
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      handleClick()
    }, 5000)
  })

return (
  <button onClick={handleClick}>Autoclickable</button>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The button will be clicked every 10 seconds, you can use ref to click the button wherever you want:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function App() {
  const button = useRef();
  const interval = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    interval.current = setInterval(() => {
      button.current.click();
    }, 10000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval.current);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        type="button"
        ref={button}
        onClick={() => { console.log('button clicked') }}
      >
        AutoClickable
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```